# Listing subfolders recursivelly on FTP server

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

My problem is to get the paths of all files on the FTP server in Java. I want to be able to make `List<String>` of the paths of all files on on the server. I need this, to be able to determine, if a file exists on the server that is not on a local computer and vice versa. How do I get a list of the paths for each file on the server?

like:

```
... 
List<String> templist = new LinkedList<>();
String strings[] = someMethod()
for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
    templist.add(strings[i]);
} 
...
```

That when `.forEach(System.out::println())` is run over the `templist` displays something like:

```
xxx.txt 
foo/bar.txt
foo/b/y.txt
```

I'm using the Apache Commons FTP library in Java.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the [`FTPClient.mlistDir` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistDir(java.lang.String))
  (or [`FTPClient.listFiles`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles(java.lang.String)), if the server does not support `MLSD` command)
- Iterate the returned array of [`FTPFile`s](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html).
- For those entries where the [`FTPFile.isDirectory()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#isDirectory()) is true, call the `FTPClient.mlistDir` again.